# unable to telnet 139 port after changing IP on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, telnet

I am using ubuntu 18.04, now we are changed new ip series in this system and windows server also, then after unable to telnet 139, they show connection refuse. When we set old ip it's working fine.
any idea why this happening.
Thanks

Comment: The service is configured to only listen on the old IP, or there is a firewall that only permits connection via the old IP?

Comment: it is in intranet, so no firewall option is there and server firewall is disable. Might be that service is listen with old IP, any option to remove listen or bind on new ip.